# Why isn't this returning all of the results in this while loop?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to write a video ripper and my while loop is only returning 1 result.

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.SITE.com/categories/redhead';
$url2 = 'http://www.SITE.com/movies';
$search = file_get_contents($url);
$results = explode('"/movies', $search);
$count = count($results);
$i = 1;


while($i < 5) {
    $final = $url2 .$results[$i];
    $goodfinal = str_replace('">', ' ', $final);
    echo $goodfinal.'<br>';
    $i++;
}

?>
```

Comment: What's `$count` and `$i` vars are for, if you don't use them within the loop?

Comment: @raina77ow: They were being used on a part of the code I edited out for now. It was returning the number of videos on the page for my while loop but that crashed firefox

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use your iterator to access the correct `$results` entry:

```
$url = 'http://www.SITE.com/categories/redhead';
$url2 = 'http://www.SITE.com/movies';
$search = file_get_contents($url);
$results = explode('"/movies', $search);

$i = 0;
$length = count($results);
while($i < $length) {
    $final = $url2 .$results[$i];
    $goodfinal = str_replace('">', ' ', $final);
    echo $goodfinal.'<br>';
    $i++;
}
```

As an alternative you could loop over your results like this:

```
foreach($results as $result) {
    echo str_replace('">', ' ', $url2 . $result) . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Should move `count($results)` outside (before) the while() so as not to re-count at each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Now it's returning part of the website with my url at the bottom.

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($results);`?

Comment: A complete, crazy mess

Comment: I tried your foreach loop and it's still and crazy mess that dispays the original website with my results attacthed

Comment: I can post the actual website on here for you to run the code but I'm not sure if it's appropriate or not.

Comment: So start by cleaning your `$results`. If you have a good array you should not have any problems looping over it.